# Calculating angle of projectile motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

I realize that similar questions have been asked but I'd like to put my problem here and what I have to make sure everything is right.

So my problem is: I've got a rock $2.5$ meters above the ground and I shoot it out of a slingshot. It hits another rock which is $3.6$ meters above the ground, $14$ meters away from it's initial position $x$. The initial velocity of the rock is $15.9$ m/s.

So the formula I know is: $ \frac{1}{2} \cdot g \cdot t^2 - (v_o \cdot \sin ( \theta ) ) + y $

I also know: $x = (v_o \cdot \cos ( \theta ) ) \cdot t$

But these don't seem to help me solve my problem as I don't have $t$ nor $ \theta$.

Comment: Draw a sketch, you'll find it immensely simplifies the problem

Comment: I already did...

Comment: You have two equations and two unknowns. By the way your equation for $y$ is wrong, it should be $y(t)=-\frac{1}{2}gt^2+v_0\sin(\theta)t+y_0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an equation for the y and x positions then you can use the system to solve for your unknown variables. These are the equations you want:

$$ x = v_0cos(\theta)*t $$
$$ y = y_0 + v_0sin(\theta)*t + {1 \over 2}gt^2$$

I think those are the two equations you mentioned, except you missed a t variable in the equation for the y position, and the $v_0sin(\theta)$ term is generally added not subtracted. This way you can insert a positive or negative velocity for $v_0$ depending upon the direction.

So, you have two equations with two unknowns (t and $\theta$). If you solve one equation for t (whichever one you think is easier) and then plug the resulting expression into the other equation you should have one single equation with $\theta$ as your unknown. Also, one thing to watch out for is to make sure your signs are right. If you define the upward direction to be positive, then you have to insert -9.8 for g, and a positive velocity for $v_0$

Comment: Yeah my calculations came out wrong (89 degrees) but after like 3 hours that just has to suffice...

Now I'm asked to find the velocity of the rock as it hits the other rock, could you please point me in the right direction? I'm getting extremely tired and frustrated.

Comment: http://www.physicsforums.com/showpost.php?p=905663&postcount=2 Here is a link with a list of kinematic equations. You can usually solve all of these projectile problems with different combinations of these equations. In the case of finding a final velocity I would look for the kinematic equation that includes velocity, acceleration, and time. Remember that all of these equations are for one dimension. So you will need to make two separate equations to find the final y velocity and x velocity. Then you can find the total velocity from there.