# Calculating angle of projectile motion with constant initial velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

The following question was asked by someone few years ago but the question was answered a bit superficially. Previous question: [Calculating angle of projectile motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95398/calculating-angle-of-projectile-motion)

I want to calculate an angle $\theta$ to get the correct trajectory to hit an enemy in my video game.

I have two equations for the projectile motion.
$$ x(t) = v_0\cos(\theta)*t $$
$$ y(t) = v_0\sin(\theta)*t + {1 \over 2}gt^2$$

Now I solved the first equation for $t$ and put it in $y(t)$.

$$ y(x) = v_0\sin(\theta)*{x \over v_0\cos(\theta)}+{1 \over 2}g{x^2 \over v_0^2\cos^2(\theta)}$$

We can simplify that into 
$$ y(x) = {\sin(\theta) \over \cos(\theta)}*x+{gx^2 \over 2v_0^2\cos^2(\theta)}$$

I want to solve for $\theta$ for any point $(x,y)$, so I can multiply both sides with $\cos^2(\theta)$ to get a quadratic equation, and then substitute $\cos(\theta)$ with $u$, like
$$ 0 = -y \cos^2(\theta) + \sin(\theta)\times x\cos(\theta) + {gx^2 \over 2v_0^2}$$
$$ \cos(\theta) = u$$

The problem is, that I can't solve this in a regular way. I type that in mathematica, and got this:

$$\theta=-\cos^{-1}\cfrac{\sqrt{-\cfrac{\sqrt{-x^4(g^2x^2+2gv^2y-v^4)}}{v^2(x^2+y^2)}-\cfrac{gx^2y}{v^2(x^2+y^2)}+\cfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Does someone have an idea or had a similar problem?

Comment: Thank you so much, for some reason I didn't read that part in the wiki article :(

Answer (score 0):

The angle depends on where the target is at intercept (x,y) and the velocity of the projectile and target. It is not an easily solved problem. If your weapon is moving very much faster than your target you may be able to assume the target is stationary. In that case, just substitute x,y for the location of the target, and input the value of v.